# WCF and Linq 2 SQL

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, rest

I'm trying to expose a simple WCF REST service using data from Linq to SQL.

The problem is when I have child objects (like a User object which has UserAction objects as children) - I get an empty result from the service. As it seems - the service it self is working and the data is being fetched from Linq as needed, but at the client side - no data is being shown.

If I delete all the child objects, it works just fine.

Any Ideas why this happens and how to fix?

EDIT: added the webservice code for that part

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "TopUpdaters/{topx}",
        ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<User> TopUpdaters(string topx)
{
   FulltankRepository rep = new FulltankRepository();
   var topusers = rep.GetTopUpdaters(int.Parse(topx));

   return topusers;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u try making a unit test of method and see weather data is comming or not from service?? if not then is there a error in service?? place Try {} catch{} block to see is there any error comming when fetching records

Comment: and do check that Linq query of fetching child records, i guess there is problem as u already said that it is displaying data when there is no child

Comment: Can you show us the service contract interface signature?

Comment: No errors - all works just fine up until "return" of the service. all being returned as needed. Just the exposed service is not working after all :)

Comment: added the code for the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've confirmed that the children exist in memory on the server, then it sounds like a serialization issue. Check that your UserAction property on User is marked for serialization

```
[DataMember]
public List<UserAction> UserActionChild
{
get;
set;
}
```

Comment: Ok - that was the answer. Had to change serialization to unidirectional in Linq editor - which added the needed serialization as you mentioned.